# How to remove "Compare with - each other" pop up menu item from package explorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have one plugin for eclipse project explorer. I want to modify the pop up menu in project explorer.

I added one activity for which pattern binding has one pattern entry as

```
pattern=".*/org.eclipse.compare.*">
```

this removes all sub items under "Compare with" except the "Each other" option.

Can some one help me in removing this option from pop-up menu.

I also tried an altogether different activity pattern binding with pattern as

```
isEqualityPattern="true"
pattern="org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditor">
```

but , it fails.

Answer (score 0):

'Compare with each other' is contributed by the `org.eclipse.team.ui` plugin and has the id `org.eclipse.team.ui.compareWithEachOther`

I used the Menu Spy component of [Eclipse Plugin Spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html) to determine the details of the menu item.

Comment: I tried this id. Not working.
And by the way, when I click on "Compare with each other" I get an error saying  -- " Unable to open editor, unknown editor ID : org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditor ".... so I don't understand how do org.eclipse.team.ui plugin contributes this editor.....
please help me understand this.....

Comment: The Team plugin uses the compare editor to actually do the compare. I don't know why that isn't working.